# Getting error while running the Web Application?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, cassandra

I am creating a Dynamic web project. I have made a home JSP file and kept a button on this JSP page. When I click on this page then it calls the HelloServlet where I am accessing the Cassandra DataBase. I have added all the required Jars file to the project . But when I click on the button on the JSP page some exception is coming which is given here

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class cassandra.HelloServlet

type:- Exception report
message:- Error instantiating servlet class cassandra.HelloServlet
description:- The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception:-javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class cassandra.HelloServlet
............
root cause:- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransport
........................
root cause:- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport
.........   ............
```

Also , I am able to perform my job when I am creating a simple Java project using the same code and same Jars.

Looking for Help!

Comment: please show your web.xml lines..

Comment: please list all WEB-INF/libs/*.jar

Comment: my web.xml eteries are fine.

Comment: Peter When I click on the WEB-INF/libs/ the + sign present in the starting of its name disapperas . And the Jars added by me are present in Libraries under "Java Resources" .

Comment: show us the code where you written the button click event code ..

Comment: Suresh :-  <form action="HelloServlet">   
  
   <input type="submit" value="Fetch Data">      
  </form>

Comment: Exception is coming in HelloServlet.

Answer (score 2):

You have added the jar files in the project *build path*. This path is used to compile your application, but it's different from the *runtime classpath*. At runtime, the container looks for libraries in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the deployed webapp.

Under Eclipse, the libraries that must be present at runtime under WEB-INF/lib must simply be dropped in the folder `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` of your web project. Eclipse automatically adds these to the build path and adds them to the WEB-INF/lib directory if the deployed app, so that they're available also at runtime.

So, remove all the cassandra jars from your build path, and drop them in `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`. Once done, they will appear under the *Web App Libraries* node of your project.

Comment: in short ..copy all jars from eclipse and place in WEB-INF/lib folder of war folder running on server .

Comment: @TheSureshAtta: err, no. Copying jars to the deployed web app on the server each time the web app is rebuilt and redeployed is not a good idea at all. Instead, do what I suggest in my answer: fix the source project itself to make Eclipse deploy the jar files as part of the webapp.